# Kivy GUI - fill color in circle like water fill in circle container level wise

Tags: python, kivy

[image]

As shown in the image above I need to code a `.kv` file in the Kivy GUI so I can show a circle filling with color as a value increase. For 0 value it is empty as value increase circle is fill with color.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That kind of effect can be done by creating a mask for this you can use [Stencil instructions](https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.graphics.stencil_instructions.html) as shown below:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder

main_widget_kv = '''
BoxLayout:
    border: 10
    WaterFill:
        level: slider.value_normalized
        color: 1, 1, 0
    Slider:
        id: slider
        orientation: 'vertical'
        value: 50

<WaterFill@Widget>:
    level: 0.1
    width: self.height
    size_hint: None, 1
    color: 0, 0, 1
    canvas:
        StencilPush
        Ellipse:
            pos: root.pos
            size: root.size

        StencilUse

        Color:
            rgb: root.color
        Rectangle:
            pos: root.pos
            size: (root.width, root.level*root.height)

        StencilUnUse

        StencilPop
'''

class TestApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Builder.load_string(main_widget_kv)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    TestApp().run()
```

[image]

---

**Update:**

The following example shows an example of how to update the height value using a method with the help of `Clock`:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.clock import Clock
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.uix.anchorlayout import AnchorLayout
from kivy.lang import Builder

Builder.load_string("""
<WaterFill>:
    level: 0.0
    width: self.height
    size_hint: None, 1
    color: 0, 0, 1
    canvas:
        StencilPush
        Ellipse:
            pos: root.pos
            size: root.size
        StencilUse
        Color:
            rgb: root.color
        Rectangle:
            pos: root.pos
            size: (root.width, root.level*root.height)
        StencilUnUse
        StencilPop
""")


class WaterFill(Widget):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        Widget.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.delta = 0.01

        Clock.schedule_interval(self.on_timeout, 0.05)

    def on_timeout(self, *args):
        self.level += self.delta
        if self.level >= 1:
            self.delta = -0.01
        elif self.level <= 0:
            self.delta = 0.01


class TestApp(App):
    def build(self):
        lay = AnchorLayout(anchor_x='center', anchor_y='center')
        lay.add_widget(WaterFill())
        return lay


if __name__ == "__main__":
    TestApp().run()
```

Comment: Great!!! solution and thanks for the help. i changed the value of level instead of slider. but how should change that value through call from method. one more help please.

Comment: @Bhu_24 
I have added an example. If my answer helps you, do not forget to mark it as correct, if you do not know how to do it, check the [tour]

Comment: Sorry i am new user for Stack overflow. your solution is really helpful for me. thanks once again.

Comment: one more help on the same. how i change 2 or more circle fill layout with same logic. i tried by defining id but fails any way to do this??? please help

Comment: @Bhu_24 Create a new question detailing what you have tried and what are the problems you have encountered.