# Kivy GUI - fill color in circle like water fill in circle container level wise for two or more tank

Tags: python, python-2.7, kivy

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.clock import Clock
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.uix.anchorlayout import AnchorLayout
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout

Builder.load_string("""
<WaterFill>:
    id: c_canvas
    level: 0.0
    width: self.height    
    size_hint: None, 1 
    color: 0, 0, 1
    canvas:
        StencilPush
        Ellipse:
            group: 'a'            
            size: (200, 200)
            pos: 150,270             

        StencilUse
        Color:
            rgb: root.color
        Rectangle:
            group: 'a'
            pos: root.pos
            size: (root.width, root.level*root.height)
        StencilUnUse
        StencilPop

        Ellipse:
            group: 'b'
            size: (200, 200)            
            pos: 450,270 

    Button:
        text: 'Try me!'
        on_release: root.press_me()          
""")


class WaterFill(Widget):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        Widget.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.delta = 0.01

        Clock.schedule_interval(self.on_timeout, 0.05)

    def on_timeout(self, *args):        
        #self.root.ids.c_canvas.canvas.get_group('a').level += self.delta  #i tried by id and by group  but unabel to find solution
        self.level += self.delta
        if self.level >= 1:
            #self.delta = -0.01
            self.delta = -1.1
        elif self.level <= 0:
            self.delta = 0.01

    def press_me(self):
        print("pressed")  # on press need to fill circle


class TestApp(App):
    def build(self):
        #lay = AnchorLayout(anchor_x='center', anchor_y='center')
        #lay.add_widget(WaterFill())
        return WaterFill()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    TestApp().run()
```

how i change 2 or more circle fill layout with [Kivy GUI - fill color in circle like water fill in circle container level wise](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49235731/kivy-gui-fill-color-in-circle-like-water-fill-in-circle-container-level-wise) same logic. i tried by defining id but fails any way to do this??? please help how to use canvas design for 2 or more circle !!!

Comment: show what you have tried, we are not a software writing service, read [ask]

Comment: What have you tried? I see that it is practically the same code that I proposed, where does the error generate you?

Comment: i commented that part. (self.root.ids.c_canvas.canvas.get_group('a').level)  i tried by id as well as by group name then i redo all. i am not able to handle 2 circle at time.

Comment: Do not comment to understand your problem or at least indicate it in the content of your question. read [ask]

Comment: Do you want both circles to fill with color when you press the button?

Comment: Do you want to change in the same way, or do you want one to fill faster than the other?, do not give much detail and you have me confused, please take the time and endeavor to improve your question if you want us to help you

Comment: both circle fill independently and i want to start filling second circle on click and stop on click. i just need logic of level filling and calling process to fill circle rest thing i manage. as just a week ago i started coding in kivy. please help once for the same.

Comment: Do not complain if it is not clear in what you require, from what I understand you want that when the button is pressed, the filling of the right is started, and when you press the button nine times, it stops. I am right?

Comment: yes whenever button click is start fill by one step and as button goes on pressing it fill step by step.. means on nine click is fill completely as u said and then is empty on 10th click

Comment: you realize that you say one thing, and then another, you're nothing clear, I'm getting bored, I'm not in your head, I do not think and I do not know what you have in mind. Explain: when to fill and when to stop filling, when the filling is cleaned?

Comment: start filling on 1st click then on 9th click it filled completely (as one click fill one step of circle) and on next click means 10th one it again become empty.

Comment: okay, I understand, one last question, that button only controls the second circle? What happens to the left circle?

Comment: only control 2nd circle because i want only logic to handle 2 or more circle that i will manage by logic which will given by you. thanks in advance. keep left one as it is automatically filling

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to handle it, each one should easily consider the drawing independently, and that is what I proposed in my previous answer.

In the following example we use a layout to locate it and use the ids to access the values.

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout

root = Builder.load_string(""" 
<WaterFill@Widget>:
    level: 0
    color: 0, 0, 1
    canvas:
        StencilPush
        Ellipse:
            pos: root.pos
            size: root.size
        StencilUse
        Color:
            rgb: root.color
        Rectangle:
            pos: root.pos
            size: (root.width, root.level*root.height)
        StencilUnUse
        StencilPop  

<FloatLayout>:
    WaterFill:
        id: left
        level: 0.4
        pos_hint:  {'x' : 0.10, 'y': 0.4}
        size_hint: 0.4, 0.4
    WaterFill:
        id: right
        pos_hint:  {'x' : 0.55, 'y': 0.4}
        size_hint: 0.4, 0.4
    Button:
        id: button
        text: 'text'
        size_hint: .25, .25
        on_press: root.press_me()
""")

class Principal(FloatLayout):
    def press_me(self):
        current_level = self.ids["right"].level
        self.ids["right"].level = 0.0 if current_level >= 1.0 else current_level + 1.0/9

class TestApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Principal()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    TestApp().run()
```

Note:

I recommend reading about the kivy language, how the design of the .kv is linked with the .py

Comment: Thanks for code but code not working is stuck to half fill circle and won't take any filling action on button press

Comment: @Bhu_24 
I have updated the code, I developed it for python3 but after I fixed by your tag that you use python2, try my new code.

Comment: thanks for code. but it won't work. it stuck to half fill circle and on click there is no any kind of action happened

Comment: @Bhu_24 
The one you see half full is the circle on the left, have you used the new code?

Comment: @Bhu_24 
I have modified the code, copy the code back, the changes are minimal but important: `self.ids["right"].level = 0.0 if current_level >= 1.0 else current_level + 1.0/9`

Comment: yes now to works on click but left one is stuck to half fill only

Comment: change the level: `WaterFill:
        id: left
        level: **some_f_value**
        pos_hint:  {'x' : 0.10, 'y': 0.4}
        size_hint: 0.4, 0.4`

Comment: @Bhu_24 
Do you know about inheritance and composition?

Comment: inheritance in which base class properties ahe inherit to child class. no idea about Composition

Comment: Read then, those concepts are the ones that are being used @ indicates the inheritance. and children widgets that are not heirs or inherit, are being used as a composition. One thing is the children of the class inheritance and the other is the children by the hierarchy.

Comment: ok @eyllanesc actually i had less time in hand for development and kivy is new platform for me. i learned this in last week and that's why facing issue in merging 2 seperate code. please help once. if possible can you open chat session

Comment: I'm not going to help him anymore, I do not care how long ago or why he wants to do crazy things in a disorderly and low quality way. I am not a tutor, take a course or pay someone to do their job. bye.

Comment: ok sorry for inconvenience because of my stupid questions as i already told i had less time for development. Atleast give me some reference regarding kivy tutorial where i got idea about class handling in kivy

Comment: thnaks bro for help and if possible then only help me to resolve this my last question. because i am badly stuck on the same rest all thing i done. :(

Comment: No, I will not.

Comment: Please help once.. from yesterday i am trying. only help for WaterFill@Widget how to add this